# Proving the algorithm that orders an array according to the specified positions

Tags: algorithms, arrays

I have the following task:

> Given an array `a` holding positions and array `b` holding values,
>   order the elements in the array `b` according to the positions in the array `a`. For the
>   input:
>
> ```
> a = [3, 0, 1, 2]; 
> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
> ```
>
> the output should be
>
> ```
> [ 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a' ]
> ```

I have written a simple algorithm which simply an item into the specified position by swapping:

```
// a.lenght -1 since the last element will end up in the correct vacant position
for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    const position = a[i];
    swap(b, i, position);
}
```

Although I've tested it and it seems to produce correct results, I can't figure how to prove it works correctly. Can anyone please help with reasoning?

Comment: Your algorithm isn't correct

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove a false statement to be true :P

Consider this example:

```
a = [1, 2, 0]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Output should be:

```
b = ['c', 'a', 'b' ]
```

But your algorithm will output:

```
b = ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

This because when you swap an element in its "final" position `a[i]` it's possibile that in one of the next loops that element will be swapped again.

To solve this problem think about swapping `a[ ]` elements too. :)

Comment: thanks, _it's possibile that in one of the next loops that element will be swapped again_ - I thougt of that that's why I wanted a proof. can you please elaborate on _To solve this problem think about swapping a[ ] elements too._?

Comment: Hint: when you `swap(b, i, a[i])`, `a[ a[i] ]!=a[i]` except when `i=a[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Let us run a test case on your algorithm.Let us have two arrays

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[b,g,d,e,h,c,a,f];
```

As you can see that each element in array `a` is actually the index if there was an array `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]`. So the output should produce them in the order a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

But here's the output of your algorithm
At `i=0` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,b,d,e,h,c,a,f];
```

At `i=1`

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,c,d,e,h,b,a,f];
```

At `i=2` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,c,e,d,h,b,a,f];
```

At `i=3` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,c,e,h,d,b,a,f];
```

At `i=4` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,c,e,h,f,b,a,d];
```

At `i=5` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[g,c,b,h,f,e,a,d];
```

At `i=6` you get the output

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[a,c,b,h,f,e,g,d];
```

At `i=7`

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[a,c,b,h,f,d,g,e];
```

If your algorithm was correct then at `i=7` the output should be

```
a=[1,6,3,4,7,2,0,5];
b=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];
```

So the algorithm doesn't work.